# ReactJS Redux Api Fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just need a little help with regards to fetching of data through an api

currently I have this code in my container

```
    fetchAll: () => {
        Promise.resolve(token.getToken()).then( (response) => {
            let obj = {
             token_type: response.data.token_type,
             access_token: response.data.access_token   
            }

            apiFetch("http://dev.apiserver.com/api/all",{
              "method": "GET",
              "headers": {
                "Authorization": `${obj.token_type} ${obj.access_token}`,
                "userId": 1
              }
            })
            .then( (res) => {
                return res.json();
            }).then( (json) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'FETCH_ALL',
                    payload: json
                })
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            })
        })
    }
```

I'm calling the above function from componentWillMount(), I can successfully log the result in my console

here is my reducer code

```
    const allReducer = (state: Immut = initialState, action: { type: string, payload: any }) => {
        switch (action.type) {
          case FETCH_ALL:
            let newState = state
            let payload = action.payload

            newState = Immutable.fromJS(payload)
            console.log(newState)

            return newState
        }
    }
```

the problem is that it doesn't update the state or re-render the components

Answer (score 0):

Since your reducer is getting called, the issue is likely **not** in the AJAX call or the update part of the Redux cycle, but in how your component connects to the state. Changes in the state should reactively trigger a re-render of the component, but for this to happen, the props of the component need to change. First, a few steps on how you might debug this issue, before some suggestions of possible causes, and suggested best practices.

### Redux Dev Tools

- Install [Redux Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) on Chrome. DevTools allow you to view a history of actions, and the changes each action induced to the Redux state.
- First, use Redux DevTools to ensure that the shape of your Redux state is what you expect, even before triggering any action / AJAX call.
- Then, select your *AJAX fetch success* (FETCH_ALL) action in Redux DevTools and, looking at the *diff*, see that the state changes as you expect.

### Manual debugging

- Try putting a debug value in the *initialState* of your reducer, and ensure it renders on the component.
- See that the props of the component are updated when state changes. Put a *console.log* for **this.props** and **nextProps** in the life-cycle method [componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

### Issues to look for

- Your component may be looking for the data in a wrong place of the state. The structure of your store follows the composition of your reducers. For example, the following puts the output of *myDataReducer* under *app.db*:

  ```
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    app: combineReducers({ db: myDataReducer }),
  });
  ```
- You seem to be using Immutable.js. Vanilla Redux treats the state as a [POJO](http://g-liu.com/blog/2015/08/object-oriented-programming-javascript-using-pojos-for-good/). You should either A) use a JavaScript object as the root of your state, or B) use a special *combineReducers* from [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable).

### Best practices

- Trigger data fetching from [*componentDidMount*](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/790581793397305345) instead of *componentWillMount*.
- Trigger all side effects with an Redux action, instead of chaining promises directly in component code. Effect those changes using Redux middleware, like [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/). In your case, you could use [redux-promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise), create an action like

  ```
  const action = ({type: FETCH_DATA, payload: axios.get(ENDPOINT, params)});
  ```

  The *redux-promise* middleware handles the resolving, so that your reducer will only see the resolved value in the payload.

Comment: According to Redux Dev Tool, it doesn't dispatch the FETCH_ALL action

Comment: Looking at the _network_ tab in Chrome dev tools, does your ajax call start and complete successfully? (You can set XHR filter in dev tools to exclude other network traffic)

Answer (score 0):

You're dispatching type `'FETCH_ALL'` and catching case `FETCH_ALL`. One is a variable and one is a string.